# Treeview onNodeSelected not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

Im using the Jon Miles treeview from https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview

I have generated a JSON data structure and the treeview displays nicely, however I cannot make the onNodeSelected event fire.

JS:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-treeview.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />    

<script>
    $(function () {

        var defaultData = @Html.Raw(broadcaster.GetTreeViewData()); //Getting data from C# data structure 

        $('#tree').treeview({

            color: "#428bca",
            data: defaultData,
            levels: 2
        });
    });

    $('#tree').treeview({
        onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
            alert('selected:')
        }});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<li>
   <div id="tree"></div>
</li>
```

edit:
also tried the jQuery on()but no luck - nothing happens.

```
$('#tree').on('nodeSelected', function(event, data) {
        alert('selected:')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are initializing nodes 2 times.. 
it should be like this...

```
 $(function () {

        var defaultData = @Html.Raw(broadcaster.GetTreeViewData()); //Getting data from C# data structure 



           $('#tree').treeview({

                color: "#428bca",
                data: defaultData,
                levels: 2,
     onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
                alert('selected:')
            }
            });
        });
```